# Serving HTML files from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: html, google-app-engine, cdn

Is there really anything wrong with using a CDN to serve static HTML files, like any webserver?

We are developing a CMS on Google App Engine and are tinkering with the idea of providing publishing to static html files. This is accomplished in minutes using the Google Cloud Storage Python API for Google App Engine.

But while the HTML file is delivered fine in other browsers, Chrome automatically downloads the HTML files locally and does not open then in a browser tab.

Any direction appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not wrong and most likely your `Content-Type` is wrong or the `Content-Disposition`.

When you're creating a file using the [Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#Using_Google_Storage) set the `mime_type` to `'text/html'` and skip the `content_disposition`.

Comment: thanks for the insight... but it still doesn't seem to be working for me. my python code is simple enough `writable_file_name = files.gs.create(filename, acl='public-read', mime_type='text/html')` and the meta tag produced seems simple enough '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' but chrome still auto downloads the file.

Comment: i additionaly find it odd that any browser would auto download a file to a device without requesting permission!

Comment: @user1224611 Strange.. for files that are safe there is no need to ask for permission. Would you mind sharing the link so I can test it on different browsers and dig more into it?

Comment: the information you've provided is sufficient to solve my problem. i've determined that i'm having problems with the google cloud storage cache which is holding my old file with the incorrect content type. all other testing with a new file name is working as expected. thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: @user1224611 I'm glad it worked.. and if it's sufficient then you should accept the answer.. :)